# How do I ensure that a CRM On-Prem server is running TLS 1.2

Tags: ssl, microsoft-dynamics-crm

We have a few servers here running CRM 2016 On-Premise, and we need to make sure that they are running TLS 1.2 as TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 is about to stop working as far as i understand it.

How can I make sure that this is the case? The CRM solutions are running custom workflows, but I don't believe any of them is coded to specifically run TLS 1.0 / 1.1. So is there any global setting I can set somewhere that I can use, and is there a way to test it out before and after I change the setting to make sure it running TLS 1.2 after the change?

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that CRM directly manages, it depends on IIS (which in turn depends on Windows).

You can use [IISCrypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/) to easily examine and change the system cryptography settings in any Windows OS.